# How to debug javascript in Angular 5 app in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I created an Angular 5 web app with VS2017.

The app worked until I enabled javascript debugging.
After that I now get this error when then app launches.

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Note:
My solution has multiple startup projects.

```
1. API  
2. UI
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the Visual Studio error pertaining to reservations.  I would just try to change your port it generates.  Go to the project that is starting up, right click and select properties.  On the left side select 'Debug'.  Under 'Web Server Settings' near the bottom change the 'App URL:' to use another port.  This may or may not fix the issue as I have at times gotten the temp directories that hosts this location junked up.

Comment: Well I would try a few other things then.  Can you clean and rebuild?  When you say you have multiple startup projects can you turn it to just your API to start and that works?  Can you run the angular app detached from Visual Studio with Angular commands directly?  EG: If your Angular App is 4 and up you probably have Angular CLI for it and could run something like 'ng serve --open' from a command line that is parallel to the package.json file in the angular app.